# rails 3 namespace resources routing exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm building JSON api controllers.

my routes.rb has:

```
namespace :api do
  resources :users
end
```

controllers/api/users.rb:

```
respond_to :json
def create
  @user = User.create(params[:user])
  respond_with(@user)
end
```

when posting to api/users.json a new user is created but I'm getting an exception saying user_url method is missing.
if i add: resources :users to routes.rb everything is fine.
what's happening? any other way to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think respond_with(@user) will redirect to user url but there is no users path declared outside namespace :api, so it alerts that error.

Could you try this?

```
respond_with(@user, :location => your_path_that_will_be_redirected)
```

Comment: ok, I found out that I should use render :json for what I'm trying to do.